# Unable to update report name in protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter

Tags: protractor, cucumber, report

Report is not generated with the name mentioned in config.js

I have updated the options for plugin with report name

```
Config.js

   plugins: [{
    package: require.resolve('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'),
      options:{
        automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
        removeExistingJsonReportFile: true,
        reportName : "Test",
        reportPath:  "C:/Cucmber/reports" 
      }
  }
```

I expect report with name "Test.html" to be generated but the report name is "index.html"

Answer (score 0):

set `automaticallyGenerateReport` to `fasle`.

Hope it helps you